# Does a GUI-class argument violate thread-safety in tkinter?

Tags: python, multithreading, class, tkinter, instance

I learned the hard way that tkinter is not thread-safe when starting independent threads with tkinter functionality from the main tkinter thread. I got error messages in a (for me) non-reproducible way, mostly "main thread is not in main loop" in connection to internal **del** calls after I stopped my application. Sometimes the kernel crashed during or after execution, often everything just ran smoothly.

These independent threads should run data acquisitions (DAQ) at a couple of instruments, with different GUIs depending on the type of instrument. Threading seems to be feasible as it is not known from start which instrument will be needed at some time, DAQ tasks should be queued up if an instrument is busy etc.

So, my idea now is to start the DAQ threads without any tkinter functionality from the main thread. The specific DAQ thread knows which specific GUI to use and puts this specific GUI class into a queue which is handled in the main GUI/tkinter thread. The instance of the GUI class will then be created in the GUI/tkinter thread.

Will this approach still violate thread-safety or is everything ok, as long as the GUI instances are created in the main tkinter thread?

Comment: You can certainly get away with threading in a tkinter app (I've done it), but what you *can't* (or perhaps more accurately, *shouldn't*) do is call any tkinter methods from those threads. What this means is that your GUI needs to exist only in the main thread. You can create other threads to handle other jobs (like DAQ) and return values from those threads using, for example, queues.

Comment: @JRiggles, that is exactly the approach. I was just wondering whether having a reference to a GUI class (without instantiating it) in a DAQ thread would spoil this concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you only access tkinter widgets and functions from a single thread, it should work just fine. One exception, as far as I understand, is that it's safe to call the `event_genereate` method from other threads. You can push data on a queue and then generate an event, then the event can be handled in the main thread where data can be pulled off the queue and processed.

Comment: Thank you. Then I will try it this way, just wanted to avoid more surprises. The `event_generate` method might come handy, I'll check it out.